# Generate a lot of data, and load in NSTableView in real time

Tags: swift, macos, asynchronous, nstableview

I'm new to the OS X development, and when I want show the data I generate(about 100000 rows) in the NSTableView, I found that the tableview's refresh is not very smoothly. I want the tableview to refresh when every new data is generated, and people can realize this process by their eyes.

Here's a part of my code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) { () -> Void in

        //var endTime: NSTimeInterval!

        for i in 1...100000 {
            //generate
            self.models.append(DBMSModel(time: self.generateTime(NSTimeInterval(i)), money: Float(i), payType: self.payType[i % 4], payPlace: self.place[i % 4]).contentData)

//                endTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.mainTableView.reloadData()

                let numOfRows = self.mainTableView.numberOfRows

                if numOfRows > 0 {
                    self.mainTableView.scrollRowToVisible(numOfRows - 1)
                }
            })

        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ResultAlert", sender: endTime - startTime)
        })
//            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ResultAlert", sender: endTime - startTime)
    }
```

I use a new thread to generate data, and then notify the main thread to refresh tableview, but what I can realize is that the tableview refreshed just about four times. How can I improve this code to make the UI refreshing more efficiently?

Comment: Do less work on the main queue, make sure you only update the UI there nothing else.

Comment: Yes, there is just reloaddata and scroll to the last line in the main thread. Generating data is in another thread

Answer (score 0):

Well, I seem to solve this problem in a foolish way...

```
for i in 1...100000 {
            //generate
            self.models.append(DBMSModel(time: self.generateTime(NSTimeInterval(i)), money: Float(i), payType: self.payType[i % 4], payPlace: self.place[i % 4]).contentData)

            endTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970

            if i > 100 {
                if i % (i / 100) == 0 {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        self.mainTableView.reloadData()

                        self.mainTableView.scrollToEndOfDocument(nil)
                    })
                }
            }

        }
```

Just reduce the tableview's reloaddata times to 100 times, and I found that the UI animation was more smoothly than before...